# Case when Not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am beginner In T-Sql, I am creating concatenation string using case when, However    its throwing error.
Please point me out where syntax is wrong..

```
Declare @intCnt int;
Declare @strQuery Varchar(max);
Set @intCnt=1;
set @strQuery='';
While @intCnt<25
Begin
Case @strQuery
    When @strQuery='' then 
        Set @strQuery='Select Doctot_ID,Product_ID,'+ Cast(@intCnt as varchar(2))  +' As Month_ID,''NRx'' as Metric,PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as Sales From Cube_Train_Prescription Where  Cast(PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as int) <>0'
    else
        Set @strQuery=@strQuery + Char(13) + Char(10) + ' Union '+ Char(13) + Char(10) + ' Select Doctot_ID,Product_ID,'+ Cast(@intCnt as varchar(2)) +' As Month_ID,''NRx'' as Metric,PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as Sales From Cube_Train_Prescription Where  Cast(PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as int) <>0'
    End
End
Set @intCnt=@intCnt+1
End
Print @strQuery
```

Comment: don't use `Begin` and `and` inside when and else.

Comment: Initially I tried it without Begin and End inside When, Again I removed but Giving Error where Case starts

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL's `CASE` statement can only be used to return a single atomic value - it cannot be used to execute code. It's not equivalent to `switch` in C#!

You'll need to modify your code to be something like:

```
DECLARE @intCnt INT;
DECLARE @strQuery VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @intCnt = 1;
SET @strQuery = '';

WHILE @intCnt < 25
BEGIN
   SET @strQuery =
         CASE 
            WHEN @strQuery='' 
              THEN 'Select Doctot_ID,Product_ID,'+ Cast(@intCnt as varchar(2))  +' As Month_ID,''NRx'' as Metric,PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as Sales From Cube_Train_Prescription Where  Cast(PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as int) <>0'
            ELSE 
                @strQuery + Char(13) + Char(10) + ' Union '+ Char(13) + Char(10) + ' Select Doctot_ID,Product_ID,'+ Cast(@intCnt as varchar(2)) +' As Month_ID,''NRx'' as Metric,PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as Sales From Cube_Train_Prescription Where  Cast(PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as int) <>0'
         END

    SET @intCnt = @intCnt + 1
END

PRINT @strQuery
```

See the freely available [online documentation on `CASE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Use Case inside the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN <PREDICATE> THEN <RESULT> ELSE <RESULT> END
```

Comment: Thanks, However I am asking for creating string not in between the query

Comment: You should declare a variable then use it in case inside the select statement. DECLARE @I INT=1
SELECT CASE WHEN @I!=0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END

Comment: My Question is Can we use Case when like If Else because I am able to Create string when I am using If else statement in same code

Comment: The case is using inside the select statement, and the select statement is for returning something back and show some result, you should use case instead of IF only when you are returning some data. But when you use SET clause inside select statement it is not gonna to work because it is expecting to returning something.So use IF in this situations.

Comment: You can not use case outside of a select statement and you can't use Case when like If Else.

Answer (score 0):

User if else conditional statement to make query. (Case When) is used when you want to get/put values on some condition basis

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do not need the CASE statement here. You're only using the case statement to check if it's the first iteration of the loop.  You can just pull that piece out of the loop.

```
DECLARE @intCnt INT;
DECLARE @strQuery VARCHAR(MAX);


SET @strQuery = 'Select Doctot_ID,Product_ID,1 As Month_ID,''NRx'' as Metric,PROD_NRx_1 as Sales From Cube_Train_Prescription Where  Cast(PROD_NRx_1 as int) <>0'
SET @intCnt = 2;

WHILE @intCnt < 25
BEGIN
    SET @strQuery = @strQuery + Char(13) + Char(10) + ' Union '+ Char(13) + Char(10) + ' Select Doctot_ID,Product_ID,'+ Cast(@intCnt as varchar(2)) +' As Month_ID,''NRx'' as Metric,PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as Sales From Cube_Train_Prescription Where  Cast(PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as int) <>0'

    SET @intCnt = @intCnt + 1
END

PRINT @strQuery
```

Answer (score -1):

Just **edit** `When @strQuery=''` to `when ''`

```
Case @strQuery
When '' then 
    Set @strQuery='Select Doctot_ID,Product_ID,'+ Cast(@intCnt as varchar(2))  +' As Month_ID,''NRx'' as Metric,PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as Sales From Cube_Train_Prescription Where  Cast(PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as int) <>0'
else
    Set @strQuery=@strQuery + Char(13) + Char(10) + ' Union '+ Char(13) + Char(10) + ' Select Doctot_ID,Product_ID,'+ Cast(@intCnt as varchar(2)) +' As Month_ID,''NRx'' as Metric,PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as Sales From Cube_Train_Prescription Where  Cast(PROD_NRx_'+ Cast(@intCnt as Varchar(2)) +' as int) <>0'
End
```